# SVM classifier is not getting saved in ".xml"?

Tags: c++, xml, opencv, filesystems, libsvm

I am trying to train a SVM with SIFT descriptors taken from images. And then i want to save the SVM in `.xml` format so that i can load it again.

**My structure:** I have 10 classes with 100 samples from each class.

**Question:** If i use 10-50 samples for each class then the SVM gets saved and i can see a `classifer.xml` file in my folder. But if i want to use more samples e.g. ~100 samples per class, then the SVM is not getting saved.

I thought that it might take some time for it to save but i have already waited for so long (and i have done it several times).

My code for SVM training is following:

```
void svm::svmTrain()
{
    cv::Mat trainme;        // it should contain the feature vectors
    cv::Mat labels; // it will contain the class labels

    createTrainingDateUsingBOW( trainme, labels);       

    //svm parameters
    CvTermCriteria criteria = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 1000, FLT_EPSILON);
    CvSVMParams svm_params = CvSVMParams (CvSVM::C_SVC, CvSVM::POLY, 10.0   ,  8.0   , 1.0   , 10.0  , 0.5 , 0.1 , NULL         , criteria); //CvSVMParams --it is a struct
                                       //( svm_type,    kernel_type, degree , gamma , coef0 , Cvalue, nu   , p  , class_weights, term_crit)

    cout<<"\n saving SVM \n";

    cv::SVM svm;
    svm.train(trainme, labels, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), svm_params);
    svm.save("classifier.xml");

    cout<<"\n SVM classifier is saved.";

}
```

**PS:** ***So if my samples are more 40-60 per class then, i reach upto `saving SVM` from the above code but never reach to `SVM classifier is saved.`***

Answer (score 1):

try this replacement, you ll find that, its taking too much time for training, after training, it hardly takes a minute to save the file.

```
cout<<"\n training SVM \n";

cv::SVM svm;
svm.train(trainme, labels, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), svm_params);
cout<<"\n saving SVM \n";
svm.save("classifier.xml");

cout<<"\n SVM classifier is saved.";
```

I never personally experienced with SVM but, with as many as 1000 samples, it won't train in less than an hour. In my case when i tried things for fishers with similar number of samples, it took more than 2-3 hours.

Comment: with 35 samples/class, it is getting saved within a minute but if i chose 40samples/class...it is not getting saved..isn't weird ? (I haven't tried your suggestion yet)

Comment: oh, yeah, it sounds weird, couldn't possibly guess the reason for that.